# Getting table values once the for-do loop is over

Tags: for-loop, multidimensional-array, lua

I have coded the following function, to draw a grid on the screen (using FlyWithLua in X-Plane 10).

It works and paints the grid as it should, boxes/labels and everything, and obviously it creates the "*lt_box*" three dimensional array as when I print in the loop (the commented out print instructions) it prints the correct values.

The issue is, if I call lt_box[x][y][z] from any other part of the code I can't get to those values...

any idea?

```
function draw_lt_table()
    idx = 1
    idx2 = 1
    xx1 = rth_box[1]
    xx2 = rth_box[2]
    yy1 = rth_box[3]
    yy2 = rth_box[4]
    lite_idx = 1
    cell_x_size = 38
    cell_y_size = 40

    num_cols = 6
    num_rows = 6

    lt_box = {}

        if d_tab==false or d_stg==false then
            return lt_box
        end

        for idx2 = 1,num_rows,1 do
            for idx = 1,num_cols,1 do
                lt_box[idx] = {}
                lt_box[idx][idx2] = {xx1+((cell_x_size*idx)-cell_x_size), xx1+(cell_x_size)*idx, 1+yy2+((cell_y_size*idx2)-cell_y_size), 1+yy2+(cell_y_size)*idx2}  
                graphics.set_color(0, 0, 0, 0.7)
                graphics.draw_rectangle(lt_box[idx][idx2][1], lt_box[idx][idx2][3], lt_box[idx][idx2][2], lt_box[idx][idx2][4])
                graphics.set_color(1, 1, 1, 0.7)
                graphics.set_width(2)
                graphics.draw_line(lt_box[idx][idx2][1],lt_box[idx][idx2][3],lt_box[idx][idx2][1],lt_box[idx][idx2][4])
                graphics.draw_line(lt_box[idx][idx2][1],lt_box[idx][idx2][4],lt_box[idx][idx2][2],lt_box[idx][idx2][4])
                graphics.draw_line(lt_box[idx][idx2][2],lt_box[idx][idx2][4],lt_box[idx][idx2][2],lt_box[idx][idx2][3])
                graphics.draw_line(lt_box[idx][idx2][2],lt_box[idx][idx2][3],lt_box[idx][idx2][1],lt_box[idx][idx2][3])
                light_up(unpack(lt_box[idx][idx2]))
                glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 0.7)
                draw_string(lt_box[idx][idx2][1]+12, lt_box[idx][idx2][3]+30, lite_idx)
                draw_string(lt_box[idx][idx2][1]+3, lt_box[idx][idx2][3]+15, lites_vars[4][lite_idx])
                draw_string(lt_box[idx][idx2][1]+3, lt_box[idx][idx2][3]+5, lites_vars[lt_set][lite_idx])
                lite_idx = lite_idx+1 -- this is usd in line 115-116 to select values as labels 
            --[[
            print("LT_BOX " .. idx .. " " .. idx2 .. " x1 ".. lt_box[idx][idx2][1])
            print("LT_BOX " .. idx .. " " .. idx2 .. " x2 ".. lt_box[idx][idx2][2])
            print("LT_BOX " .. idx .. " " .. idx2 .. " y1 ".. lt_box[idx][idx2][3])
            print("LT_BOX " .. idx .. " " .. idx2 .. " y2 ".. lt_box[idx][idx2][4])
            print("****************************************************************************")
            --]]
            end
        --print("____________________________________________________________________________")
        end

end
```

Comment: `lt_box` is not local to `draw_lt_table` so you should be able to use values assigned in `draw_lt_table` any time after calling `draw_lt_table`. Please edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 4):

You have `lt_box[idx] = {}` in the inner loop, which means you reset that table every time you add an element. You have to create that table in the outer loop.

```
for idx = 1,num_cols,1 do
  lt_box[idx] = {}
  for idx2 = 1,num_rows,1 do
```